# Where does SimObject name get set?

Tags: gem5

I want to know where does SimObject names like mem_ctrls, membus, replacement_policy are set in gem5. After looking at the code, I understood that, these name are used in stats.txt.

I have looked into SimObject code files(py,cc,hh files). I printed all Simobject names by stepping through root descendants in Simulation.py and then searched some of the names like mem_ctrls using vscode, but could not find a place where these names are set.

```py
for obj in root.descendants():
    print("object name:%s\n"% obj.get_name())
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but aren't those names simply determined by the Python attribute name assigned? E.g. `drive_sys.mem_ctrls = ...` in fs.py sets the name to `mem_ctrls`? The following yet unmerged patch may also be of interest: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/19368/5

Comment: SimObject must then just use some Python `dict()` / `getattr` / `hasattr` to loop over them.

Comment: @CiroSantilli Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

These names are the Python variable names from the configuration/run script.

For instance, from the Learning gem5 simple.py script...

```
from m5.objects import *
# create the system we are going to simulate
system = System()
# Set the clock fequency of the system (and all of its children)
system.clk_domain = SrcClockDomain()
system.clk_domain.clock = '1GHz'
system.clk_domain.voltage_domain = VoltageDomain()
# Set up the system
system.mem_mode = 'timing'               # Use timing accesses
system.mem_ranges = [AddrRange('512MB')] # Create an address range
```

The names will be `system`, `clk_domain`, `mem_ranges`.

Note that only the SimObjects will have a name. The other parameters (e.g., integers, etc.) will not have a name.

You can see where this is set here: https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/master/src/python/m5/SimObject.py#1352